# Laravel Validation - Rule to disallow request parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

In my Laravel 5.8 app I have many API routes which return paginated results. If I make a request to my API appending the following query string I can disable pagination.

```
http://api.test/users/?no_paginate=1
```

My question is... how can I disable **no_paginate** from being used on certain routes? I'd preferbly want some validation to go in the request class but I can't find anything in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You can do this using a [Global Middleware](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/middleware#global-middleware).

1. Create a `DisableNoPaginate` Middleware:

   ```
   php artisan make:middleware DisableNoPaginate
   ```
2. Then define what the middleware should do (`DisableNoPaginate.php`):

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Closure;

   class DisableNoPaginate
   {
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           //remove no_paginate param from request object
           unset($request['no_paginate']);

           return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Arrange for the middleware to run on all routes (`routes.php`):

   ```
   $app->middleware([
       App\Http\Middleware\DisableNoPaginate::class
   ]);
   ```

Now the `no_paginate` query param should be stripped from all your incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

For the best approach to get users either paginate or get all listing by below code in `UsersController`

```
public function index($type = null, Request $request)
{
    $builder = User::where(/*query*/);

    if($type == "paginate") {
        $items = $builder->paginate(10);
    } else {
        $items = $builder->get();
    }

    return view("users.index", ['users' => $items]);
}
```

Here is the route in web.php/api.php file

```
Route::get('/{type?}', ['as' => 'users.index', 'uses' => 'UsersController@index']);
```

Here url will be

```
http://api.test/users/paginate // get pagination response.
http://api.test/users          // get response without pagination
```

I think this will help you.